# Spring Boot como llamar un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedure

He visto que crean el procedimiento en la entidad utilizando @NamedStoredProcedureQueries, pero yo quisiera crearlo por seperado y despues llamarlo. Asi como JAX-RS que creaba el dao y lo llamaba, sea para insert, list, etc.

Este es mi procedimiento en sql server :

```
create proc sp_users
@opcion int = null
as
begin
 if @opcion = 1
    begin
       select * from tbusers
    end
end
```

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2018/04/25/invocar-a-procedimientos-usando-spring-boot-data-jpa/) tienes la respuesta.

Comment: Pero no entiendo porque tiene parametros IN and OUT, yo solo tengo un parametro para poder listar.

Comment: En tu caso solo tienes un parámetro `IN`, olvídate del resto

Comment: Un procedimiento almacenado es como una función implementada en la base de datos. Como toda función puede tener parámetros de entrada (IN) y retornar valores (parámetros OUT). Ambas tipos de parámetros son opcionales y dependen del procedimiento en si. En tu caso, como bien te indica @RogerTorné, solo tienes un parámetro de entrada.